# Intelephense cannot find a certain class in App/Helpers

Tags: laravel, vscode-extensions, intelephense

I have created a class in `App\Helpers\IdTransformer`
theres just two functions there.

I have registered it in aliases array in my `app.php` in `config\app`

```
'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        // 'Example' => App\Facades\Example::class,
        'IdTransformer' => App\Helpers\IdTransformer::class,
    ])->toArray(),
```

then i do, `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`

i can successfully access the file, in my code, but the Intelephense cannot find it.
and it is so annoying.
what must i do?

Comment: Did you try reloading your vscode?

Comment: also run `composer dump-autoload

Comment: i have done all those. still didn't work

Comment: > `but the Intelephense cannot find it` <<<=== it depends on how you are calling that class. Is it a variable? Then put an annotation above it, with variable name and class name. Also: install ide-helper, it will help intelephense find that class

Comment: I believe you also need to add the helper file to composer.json file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your favorite helper file in Laravel programs, you should put it in the composer.json file and provide autoload, please pay attention to the example below:

```
.
.
.
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/IdTransformer.php"
    ]
},
.
.
.
```

Add the following presentation to the ./composer.json file and in the autoload section:

```
        "files": [
        "app/Helpers/IdTransformer.php"
    ]
```

At the end type the following command:

```
composer update
```

In any part of your Laravel application, you can use the functions in IdTransformer.php as follows:

```
NameFunction();
```

At the same time, hit the  command

Answer (score 0):

What i did to solve this is,

I just put this line in the `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        ...
        "App\\Helpers\\": "app/Helpers",
        ...
    }
},
```

then i run `composer dump-autoload`